# Is it possible to configure own IP settings in Maui Blazor?

Tags: webassembly, maui

I'd like to set the IP settings for the WebView in Maui Blazor like https://localhost:6700.
Now my WebView shows the current URI as https://0.0.0.0
I am looking for some possibility to change these settings (launchsettings.json, mauiapp etc)
Is it possible to set these values?

Comment: What is your eventual goal - why do you ask this question? I haven’t checked, but I would expect URI to be the HostPage you gave BlazorWebView. Add code snippet to question. Show xaml that declares webview. Show any cs code that initializes it. And how/where are you examining current uri? If you are following some example, also give link to it.

Comment: I want to communicate with an identity provider and set my redirect uri. The uri https://0.0.0.0 is not what I'd like to have. In the Blazor App I can set it in the launchsettings.json

Comment: I can see my current url  in logs of backend or in razor pages in OnInitialized() by injecting NavigationManager

  protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            currentUrl = Navigation.Uri;
        }

Comment: All the Maui Blazor examples that I find, use the "UI' part of Blazor (HTML, JS, CSS), to make a page that is just like it would be in a browser. I don't see any mention of other aspects of ASP.NET Blazor (authentication, communication with server). I don't know for sure, but it is possible that those parts have not been ported to Maui Blazor. I recommend creating a new issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues, showing the code you would have written to set the Uri in ASP.NET Blazor, and asking how to do that for Maui's BlazorWebView. Include all info in your question and comments.